# Fill the remainder space (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I've created a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cMqTd/1/

I have three divs. A parent, a header, and a content. The header's height is unkown, and the content div should fill the remainder space.

I tried `height: 100%` but it isn't what I expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try floating the header:

```
#head {
    background: green;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It's very creative and simple. Loved it!

Answer (score 2):

Floating the header works fine (don't know why the downvotes on Bryce's answer).

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="head">head<br />head<br />head<br /></div>
    <div id="content">content</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}
#parent {
    background: red;
    height: 100%;
}
#head {
    background: green;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
#content {
    background: yellow;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

And the working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/cMqTd/3/).

[EDIT]
Changed the `height` of `#content` to `min-height`.

Comment: You should use `min-height: 100%` instead of `height` for `#content` element to fix background-color issue. http://jsfiddle.net/qolami/cMqTd/4/

Comment: @HashemQolami, you are right, saw it myself too, and fixed it :)

Comment: This comes unglued when I put long content into the content div and set it to overflow-y:auto.